# Filtering universal color on the card (i.e. multiply all vertex colors by this color) (GLES1, DirectX)

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, colorize

I have lighting turned off.  I have lots of vertices with a diffuse color component.  What I want to do is have *all* vertex colors multiplied by another color quickly (on the card!) so that I could make, say, a greyscale texture, and multiply it by Color 1,0,0 to make it draw red.

I don't have the option of turning lighting on for this, and I don't have the option of using shaders (where it'd be super easy).

So, is there some universal "multiply diffuse by" operation in OpenGL (and I'm looking for a way to do it in DirectX too) that happens quickly, without my having to run through all the vertices and do it by hand on the CPU?

Thanks!

(Even giving me a term I can google would be helpful... I can't find anything, but I realize a lot of this OpenGL is given deliberately obfuscating terms)

Edit: On a lark, I happened to google color matrix.  I see that the functionality I want exists in theory, but I'm reading it doesn't work with primitives.  Is there anything else in OpenGL that would perform this function for me, but on primitives?

Comment: Can you not solve this simply by using glColor? This will multiply all the output colours by the colour you specify. The default is (1,1,1,1).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't... I want to build a vertex buffer once, and then colorize it on the fly.  For instance, make a model of a shirt, and then let the player choose a color.  Because I could have a lot of players onscreen at one time, I don't want to have a seperately generated model for each slight color variety a shirt might have!

One workaround I COULD use is very unsatifactory... I could make, say 25+ textures that are the colors a player could use-- and use the texture matrix to point the shirt at them.  It's unsatisfactory because then I have to take up texture space pointlessly.

Comment: So lets say you are drawing 25 models on which you want different colours. Then these models may be drawn with grayscale texture but before calling each model draw method you could set the colour so the model is blended with it. This seems really straight forward or are you hiding some more information from us?

Comment: It's more like this: I have one model (a shirt) and each NPC in game could have a different color on it.  I don't want to have a new model or a new texture for each color.

So:

1. Generate vertex buffer for shirt (xyz,uv,diffuse=0xFFFFFFFF)
2. Determine what color to draw shirt
3. ????
4. Push vertex buffer to card


Remember, I have lighting turned off.  @Matic Oblak

Comment: I am sorry but either I do not understand you or the other way around. Lighting has nothing to do with this, using glColor will multiply the final source colour with the input colour so if you were to create for instance a white shirt and set colour to (0,1,0,1) it would be a green shirt. Other approach might involve stencil buffer and redrawing the scene with specific blending where you could use destination colour. But still, have you even tried to use what I suggested?